# how to use multiple broadcast to call angular controllers based on the user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on angularjs application. In my web page i have many datarange pickers. When user selects a daterange from the date picker, i need to pass the selected dates to the specific angular controller assigned to that component.Please see the below code, that is called when user selects a daterange from the daterangepicker and when click on Apply,i'm passing the selected dates to another controller using $broadcast.

```
var cb = function(start, end) {
   $('.reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  var reportStartDate  = start.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
   var reportEndDate = end.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loadSimDateCtrl', reportStartDate, reportEndDate);/*When user selects a date range in daterangepicker, this function is invoked,
    the selected date is passed to the angular controller using broadcast*/
 }
```

How to know which daterange picker is being selected when  i have multiple daterangepickers in my single html file.and based on the date selected for the specific datepicker i need to pass the daterange to the specific angular controller. Please advice.

Rough example is given [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aMfCgpssx5XtrH5kOK4r?p=preview).
When user selects a darerange from SIM Date Range ctrl, i need to call simDateCtrl by passing the selected dates.Similarly for the other date pickers too. Please advice.
In a single function `var cb = function(start, end) {. }` how to call the $broadcast which in turn calls another angular controller.

Comment: It can broadcast different events. For example $rootScope.$broadcast('loadSimDate1',reportStartDate, reportEndDate) $rootScope.$broadcast('loadSimDate2',reportStartDate, reportEndDate)

Comment: but when user selects date from 1st daterange picker i should kow that dates are selected from 1st date range picker so that i can call corresponding controller.Similarly when user selects date from 2nd daterange picker i should call know so that i can call corresponding angular controller. Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/OnvUEBzhYWsaGipUNLwC?p=preview @J Jin

Comment: The process is : When user selects date from 1st daterange picker, it uses 'ng-change="callBackend1($event)"', in callBackend1 calls broadcast 'loadSimDate1', then emit 'loadSimDate1' in corresponding controller. So for 2st daterange picker.

Comment: @JJin - can you please give a simple example in my demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OnvUEBzhYWsaGipUNLwC?p=preview

Comment: @participantjava You need not to have two controllers for the same functionality. We can customize a single controller that can take any datepicker value because the functionality of date picker throughout the app is same right

Comment: @Mr_Perfect- Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/J79hBPMTf4x4vMBKk4yk?p=preview. I'm facing similar kind of issue in my application. Initially when page is loaded i have startDate and endDate to be shown and minDate , maxDates are the dates disabled in the calendar. But in the demo you can notice, its showing start and enddate on page load but dates(minDate,maxDate) are not disabled.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect - Yes i have single controller for the date picker. When i select the date from Sim Date Range i need to call another controller, similarly for phoneDateRange i need to call another controller which i'm doing.Thankyou

Comment: They are not disabled just because of my typo mistake @participantjava. Go to my answer. I have updated in your previous question

Answer (score 2):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', MyCtrl])
  
  
  function MyCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.callBackend1 = function(event) {
      console.log('Check1')
      $rootScope.$broadcast('date1', 'start1', 'end1')
      // here call to backend, if possible do with $http service
    }
    $scope.callBackend2 = function(event) {
      console.log('Check2')
      $rootScope.$broadcast('date2', 'start2', 'end2')
      // here call to backend, if possible do with $http service
    }
    $rootScope.$on('date1', function(event, data){
      console.log(data)
    })
    $rootScope.$on('date2', function(event, data){
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
```

```html
<input class="reportrange simDateRange" ng-model="simDate" ng-change="callBackend1($event)" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Select Phone Date Range:
  <input class="reportrange phoneDateRange" ng-model="phoneDate" ng-change="callBackend2($event)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use broadcast as it propagates downwards to your nested controllers, it is not a guarantee that all child will receive that notification. Instead write a service that emits events when you are publishing and you can subscribe for that event in any of your controller. In MyCtrl you can assign different scope functions to each daterange pickers change/select events as [J Jin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681947/j-jin) pointed out.

```
;(function(angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('myApp').factory('PubSub', PubSub);
    PubSub.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

    function PubSub($rootScope) {
        var service = {};

        service.subscribe = function(eventname, callback) {
            $rootScope.$on(eventname, callback);
        }

        service.publish = function(eventname) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            var argv = {
                argv: args
            };
            $rootScope.$emit(eventname, argv);
        }

        service.unsubscribe = function(handler) {
            handler();
        }

        return service;
    }

    angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
    MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'PubSub'];

    function MyCtrl($scope, PubSub) {
        $scope.callBackend1 = function(event) {
            console.log('Check1')
            PubSub.publish('date1', 'start1', 'end1')
            // here call to backend, if possible do with $http service
        }
        $scope.callBackend2 = function(event) {
            console.log('Check2')
            PubSub.publish('date2', 'start2', 'end2')
            // here call to backend, if possible do with $http service
        }
    }

    angular.module('myApp').controller('Date1Ctrl', Date1Ctrl);
    Date1Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'PubSub'];

    function Date1Ctrl($scope, PubSub) {

        PubSub.subscribe('date1', date1Changed);

        function date1Changed(args) {
            // Do your actions here
        }
    }

    angular.module('myApp').controller('Date2Ctrl', Date2Ctrl);
    Date2Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'PubSub'];

    function Date2Ctrl($scope, PubSub) {
        PubSub.subscribe('date2', date2Changed);

        function date2Changed(args) {
            // Do your actions here
        }
    }

})(angular);
```